# ASP.NET SQL Server connection alias

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, active-directory

Probably an amateur question, but I have taken over consulting for an application a previous consulting used to do.

His ASP.NET connection strings appear to work in a way I have never seen before.
The connection string points to a server, username, password as usual yet when I look for the SQL Server account to the DB it doesn't exist nor does it appear in a UDL test file and the only account that exists in the database is a windows account.

Is there some sort of aliasing happening, and if so, where and how would I find it?

If a duplicate the database for testing using the same credentials but different db name, it fails.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the connection string you're seeing in the code or just in a config file?  If just in the config, is it possible the user/pwd is in a different file?

Comment: It is in the config. If I change the new test application web.config that is a mirror of the current working to point to the original database it works with those connection details, soon as I point it to the new database it doesn't work. (Normally would mean an orphaned account, but neither account exists in SQL security for database or system)

Comment: The only account that exists in both databases is a windows account, which should only allow integrated auth rather than sql auth. I can't use that in a connection string to work correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved.
The customer had hidden the SQL account (that was being used by the application) from our viewing even though we originally created the account.

Because the account did exist but was orphaned to the db copy, we were unable to view the database. Once added, we could access the database.

I found it very interesting that even using a UDL file, we could not see this hidden SQL account. Only Admin's (we aren't an admin) and IIS could see the account.